# I need assistance with scrapy config

Tags: scrapy, config

I need help. I'm trying to setup scrapy spider.
What is the purpose of ("/")[-2]?
What is the purpose of 'wb'?

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]  ###<<<<<< This.
        filename = f'quotes-{page}.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:     ###<<<<<< This.
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The split will turn your URL string into a list where each item is the content between the slashes.
The bracket [-2] accesses the last but one item of the list.
The 'wb' in the open function means opening a file for writing in bytes mode instead of string mode, where string mode takes care about the encoding with default UTF-8. Bytes mode will not interpret the bytes of the response body.